# break for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, authentication

I need help, I have tired all I can to break the loop but it keeps displaying the else statement print out. I am trying to figure out how to make a log in through an array and I have not been successful. SAD.
main method login

```
 import java.util.*;


 public class LogIn {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person [] people = new Person[2];
    people[0] = new Person("Heather","Ward","Davis");
    people[1] = new Person("Thomas","Cummings","Tomc84");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String current_login = "";
    String pass = "";
    int login_count = 3;


    //do{
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        current_login = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nEnter your password: ");
        pass = input.nextLine();
        outerloop:
        for (Person p: people){
            if(current_login.equals(p.getF_name())  && pass.equals(p.getPassword())){
                System.out.println("\nHello " + p.getF_name() + " " + p.getL_name());
                break outerloop;
            }
            else{
                login_count--;
                System.out.println("\nYou have " + login_count + " tries");
            }
        }

    //}while(login_count > 0 );


}
}
```

[image]

```
public class Person {
private String f_name = "";
private String l_name = "";
private String password = "";

public Person(){};

public Person(String f_name, String l_name, String password) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
    this.l_name = l_name;
    this.password = password;
}
public String getF_name() {
    return f_name;
}
public void setF_name(String f_name) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
}
public String getL_name() {
    return l_name;
}
public void setL_name(String l_name) {
    this.l_name = l_name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String toString(){
    return "first name: " + f_name +
            "Last name: " + l_name ;
}
}
```

Comment: What the heck was that picture of your IDE supposed to communicate?

Comment: Just example output I believe. The else statement prints, then the if statement prints.

Comment: Show the methods getF_name and getPassword

Comment: @Troubleshoot I added the person class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each person in your "DB" you are saying that, if the username and password are not correct, means that the user entered wrong credentials. That's wrong. You have to search the entire DB before saying "You have n tries".

Your code should be

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (Person p: people){
        if(current_login.equals(p.getF_name())  && pass.equals(p.getPassword())){
            System.out.println("\nHello " + p.getF_name() + " " + p.getL_name());
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found){
        login_count--;
        System.out.println("\nYou have " + login_count + " tries");
    }
```

Or, if you don't like it:

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (Person p: people){
        if(current_login.equals(p.getF_name())  && pass.equals(p.getPassword())){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found){
        System.out.println("\nHello " + p.getF_name() + " " + p.getL_name());
    }
    else{
        login_count--;
        System.out.println("\nYou have " + login_count + " tries");
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe instead of mucking around with the break statement, use an extra boolean flag.

```
//Change if block to set the boolean flag
if(current_login.equals(p.getF_name())  && pass.equals(p.getPassword())){
                System.out.println("\nHello " + p.getF_name() + " " + p.getL_name());
                authenticated = true;
}

//Use it in your while statement
while(login_count > 0 && !authenticated);
```

Comment: That's not the problem the OP is encountering.

Comment: my point is if all you need to do is break out of a loop, there are many ways to skin that cat. If you're getting stuck with some weird java syntax stuff, just throw in an extra boolean flag and you're all set.

Comment: Then that should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's just your loop logic that's broken. It looks like what you're trying to do is loop through the `people` array and if *no element* has the specified login, do what you have in the else. But what your loop actually does is do the else for *every element* in the array that's not the specified login (until it finds a correct one).

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
Person user = null;
for(Person p : people) {
    if(current_login.equals(p.getF_name()) && pass.equals(p.getPassword())) {
        user = p;
        break;
    }
}

if(user != null) {
    System.out.println("\nHello " + user.getF_name() + " " + user.getL_name());

} else { // do false action when 'not found'
    login_count--;
    System.out.println("\nYou have " + login_count + " tries");
}
```

Or similarly, you can put this in its own method to make the logic simpler (but you would have to change `people` so it's a static field instead of a variable declared in main or add a parameter for it):

```
static Person getUserForLogin(String name, String pass) {
    for(Person p : people) {
        if(name.equals(p.getF_name()) && pass.equals(p.getPassword())) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null; // do false action when 'not found'
}
```

Then you say:

```
Person user = getUserForLogin(current_login, pass);
if(user != null) {
    System.out.println("\nHello " + user.getF_name() + " " + user.getL_name());

} else {
    login_count--;
    System.out.println("\nYou have " + login_count + " tries");
}
```

Comment: Pff.. looks like you started off by answering using a for loop then you saw my answer and copy & pasted my example using a foreach loop.

Comment: @Troubleshoot I used a for each loop because the OP did. I submitted my answer after yours because it took longer to write. Don't be a noob.

Comment: Then why do you use a for loop in your first example? P.S; your first example wouldn't even work.

Comment: @Troubleshoot I used a for loop because that's how I typically do it myself. Your answer doesn't compile either so why don't you buzz off unless you have a real objection.

Comment: @solvator BTW thanks for the +1 but after editing my answer I actually noticed the OP has `people` declared as a variable in main. So using any kind of method here is actually more complicated. That's not to say they shouldn't change that too since it *ought* to be a field. There's just no state to speak of, only procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods *getFname* and *getPassword* must first return the first name and password for person[0] then return the username and password for person[1]. What you want to do is create a method which checks if the username or and password matches either of the two person objects, e.g;

```
public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    for(Person person : people) {
        if(username.equals(person.getF_name) && password.equals(person.getPassword()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your of all of the members of the `Person` array `people`. Since it's iterating through all of the elements, it will always first check the name and password of Heather Ward first, so you'll hit the else. You could change the `if-else` construct to something like:

```
for(Person p: people)
{
    if(current_login.equals(p.getF_name()))
    {
        if(pass.equals(p.getPassword())){
            System.out.println("\nHello " + p.getF_name() + " " + p.getL_name());
            break;
        }
        else{
            login_count--;
            System.out.println("\nYou have " + login_count + " tries");
        }
    }
    // no else at this level, we just want to see if the name exists in
    // our array.
    // If not, just continue the loop, don't give an error if the current
    // Person doesn't match!
}
```

Of course this will only reduce the number of tries (and display the warning) when you enter a correct first name but incorrect password, but it's a starting point.

Comment: I think with 'state' method it can be done more simpler.

Comment: This is just one option to fix the code making very few changes. You should post an alternative answer if you have one :-)